# Female Lifestyle website

Tags: navigation, user-expectation, user-centered-design, video, categorization

A SITUATION - I am making women's lifestyle website & there are several categories. For example, Beauty, Style, Health etc. Users can browse content related to that topic. Content will be of 3 types for every category (Articles, Slideshow, Videos).

QUESTION - Should I make specific pages to see the listing of all VIDEOS & SLIDE SHOW available in the website. And there will be option of filter by category if user wants to see the content of the particular category.

OR

Should I Give filter of video & Slideshow in a normal category page

What will be the more user centric?

[image]

Comment: Unless you are restricted by CMS using multiple taxonomies, could be useful. Say Content Type, Category and Tag. With a piece of content being able to exist in each taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who are your users? How do they browse?

I would recommend running a competitor analysis to see how your rival handle these things - If a successful site handles the filtering and sorting of video/slideshow content in a particular way then it might be worth pursuing that line - someone else has already done the research for you!

Comment: It's a good idea to always do a competitor audit. Because it's often a good idea to use patterns that are well established, that users are already familiar with.

Comment: also before committing to build features that the results are unknowns its better to test it out 1st.

Answer (score 0):

As a User, when I'm on your website browsing a particular category unless you have a very *clear indication* of the next content they're about to watch is a Video/Slideshow/Article, it's going to end up in a very confusing pattern for the user to follow.

I would highly recommend grouping your content together on the web page so that it naturally comes to the user that that particular group is for either Videos/Slideshows/Articles.

For example: [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/)'s home page consists of Articles and Videos and Photo Essays. Now if you notice, all of their Reviews and Articles are on the top of the page. Then there is a separate section for Articles. This doesn't need the user to think upon if the content they're viewing next will be a video/slideshow/article.

You could also follow tags which are boldly displayed on the title of your content to categorize it into the particular category, so users can particularly browse that category alone if they want to.

So, yes, filtering and not letting the user assume on the content he's going to see will play a big role in defining the user-experience of the website.

Comment: I added the image of navigation...Every category will contain 3 types of content (Video/Slideshow/Text article).Should I have to give separate tab for "VIDEO" & "SLIDESHOW" or it is okay to give filter inside the category?

Comment: Yes, as long as the content is different, it is okay to go granular with filters inside the categories too. You could test the user behaviour on your website and decide if filters are being used or aren't and then iterate your designs.